# Java nullpointerexception for a 2D scrolling game

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, nullpointerexception, 2d

I'm making a game, its 2D side scrolling, kinda like terraria. In my game, i have offsets, `XOff` and `YOff`, and those move the terrain. I also have a method for my character, `move()`, and all that does is this:

```
public void move() {
        if (!ableToMove) //makes sure you can move
            return;
        // x += moveX; these 2 methods work, but x and y are just my player coords.
        // y += moveY;
        core.setYOff(1); //core is my main class, where the global variables are stored
    }
```

the comments label and describe each variable. so, setYOff(1) sets the `YOff` like so:

```
private void setYOff(int i){
     YOff += i;
}
```

Now, there is only one way that i am accessing the `move` method. in a thread, called `PlayerThread`, i have a constant call to the `move()` and another method called `applyGravity()`, which doesnt really have a relevance to this question. That is in the `PlayerThread`.

Now here is the problem i'm having... When I call the `setYOff()`, I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "player Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at main.Player.move(Player.java:33)
    at main.PlayerThread.run(PlayerThread.java:24)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

which is telling me that when i'm calling the `setYOff()` method in my `move()` method, it doesnt work. I've tried just testing and moving the call to set the Y offset into the thread itself, and it gives the same error... I then tried to move it to the `RefreshThread`, and interestingly it did work... it moved the entire map down 1 pixel every 20 milliseconds... and i have no clue why! what is wrong with my move method that makes this not work, or better yet, my `PlayerThread`, that isnt making this work in the long run? What is different about my `RefreshThread`? If you guys need the entire code for everything involving the calls, creation, and such of each thread, i can provide that, but i'm not sure you would need that... What do i need to do differently? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I tried, in my `PlayerThread` just commenting out the `move()` call, and just having it adjust the y offset, and it worked! so it has to do with the move method, but again, why?

**CORRECTION TO PREVIOUS EDIT:** so testing more, i put the `move()` call back into the thread, and kept the `setYOff(1)` in it, and it still worked, but again not from within the move method itself...

Comment: If you are getting a NPE, your `core` object is null. Fix that.

Comment: alright that worked. now, i did have it setting the core object in the constructor, so why wouldnt it be working then, but it is setting it from within the method?

Comment: Only deep inspection by another pair of eyes will reveal the truth, and thou shalt be enlightened.

Comment: haha alright. if you wanna, just put your answer as an actual answer and ill accept that one :)

Comment: Posted it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` indicates that the object on which the method is being called is `Null`, in this case, the `core` object. Fix that and the problem should go away.